# Declare a variable within a function to be used outside the function (but not declare globally)

Tags: r, function, variables

If you want to declare a new variable within a function `g`, I know you can use `<<-` to declare it as Global variable.

```
g=function(t){
 a<<-t
}
g(0)
print(a)
#It gives "0"
```

What if the function `g` is already within another function `f`, and you want your function `g` to declare a new variable within the function `f` but not globally?

```
g=function(t){
   #declare the variable a and assign it the value t   
 }
f=function(t){
   g(t)
   return(a)
}
f(0)
#It should give 0.
print(a)
#It should say that the variable a is unknown.
```

Comment: From the g function, which declares a

Comment: is `a <- g(t);return(a)` an option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nest `g` in `f` and be sure to initialize `a`.

```
f = function(t){
  g = function(t){
    a <<- t
  }
  a <- NULL
  g(t)
  return(a)
}

f(0)
## [1] 0
```

If you don't want to define `g` in `f` you can dynamically insert it:

```
g = function(t){
  a <<- t
}

f = function(t){
  environment(g) <- environment()
  a <- NULL
  g(t)
  return(a)
}

f(0)
## [1] 0
```

Alternatives to `a <<- t` in any of the examples above are the following. They do not require `a` to be initialized.

```
parent.frame()$a <- t
```

or

```
assign("a", t, parent.frame())
```

For example,

```
g = function(t, envir = parent.frame()) {
  envir$a <- t
}

f = function(t) {
  g(t)
  return(a)
}

f(0)
## [1] 0
```